# Requesting PHP POST http request but PHP page detects it GET and parameters array empty

Tags: php, post, get, http-headers, http-post

When we call PHP with method POST, It is detecting a GET request and returning empty array.
I tried POSTMAN(Chrome's addon) to send POST request with keys and values and In a result it shows me GET request. Here's my data:

```
 send-mail.php:
    <?php
    echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'].'<br>';
    error_reporting(0);
    var_dump($_POST).'<br>';

    ?>

REQUEST:
link: www.xxxx.com/xxxx/xxx_xx/send-mail.php
METHOD: POST
HEADERS,
key: name
value: user1

RESPONSE:
GET
array(0) { }
```

When I tried creating form with POST request using demo.html, It works great:

```
 <form action="send-mail.php" method="POST">
   <p>name: <input type="text" name="name" /></p>
   <p>email: <input type="text" name="email" /></p>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

RESPONSE:

```
POST
array(3) { ["name"]=> string(5) "name1" ["email"]=> string(15) "name1@email.com" ["submit"]=> string(6) "Submit" }
```

I am using PHP 7.1.11. I've tried downgrading php versions 7.0,5.6.x but results are same. I have also tried using REST client(Firefox Addon).
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I hope you are selecting the POST type when sending data with Postman.

Comment: are you using post while sending in postman.

Comment: Yes. I am selecting POST when sending request.

Comment: If you can add a header, then add the entity header `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. As I recall, when a POST is made, this header is used. That's why the form submit works. Or add `Content-Type: multipart/form-data`.

Comment: I tried everything but didn't work. It is solved now. I found that when I add www.xxx.com in the link it wasn't working and xxx.com was working as expected. So I just went to Hosting Settings in the server and there was setting named "Preferred domain *". It was set to xxx.com. I enabled radio button www.xxx.com and it was start working. The third option was NONE. By enabling NONE it start accepting both www.xxx.com and xxx.com. Problem solved! Cheers!